# Navigation submenu push from top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

So, i have a simple on-click (instead of hover) "megamenu" which looks like this:
[image]

Once user clicks on the link, it is displayed under the menu overlaying anything that is bellow it.

But, instead of this, i would need this submenu (blue area) to be shown above the navigation bar (aka, pushing the nav bar and content bellow once opened) so it appears from top.

I have tried playing with absolute positioning, using several offset plugins... and nothing, i am completely stuck (JS newbie).

I was wondering could anybody help (i know i am asking a lot)...
This is the piece of code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <nav id="cbp-hrmenu" class="cbp-hrmenu">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Parent</a>
          <div class="cbp-hrsub">
            <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner"> 
              <div>
                <h4>Submenu</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>

            </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
          </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Parent 2</a>
          <div class="cbp-hrsub">
            <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner"> 
              <div>
                <h4>Submenu 2</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>

            </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
          </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Parent 3</a>
          <div class="cbp-hrsub">
            <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner"> 
              <div>
                <h4>Submenu 3</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>

            </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
          </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Parent 4</a>
          <div class="cbp-hrsub">
            <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner"> 
              <div>
                <h4>Submenu 4</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>

            </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
          </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
        </li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="display:block; height:500px">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

Fiddle is at https://jsfiddle.net/dca1eLqq/
P.S Sorry for my potentially bad english

P.P.S Due to my bad english, i havent explained it properly, so here is a quick mockup on how it should look
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqz3b.png

Comment: is this acceptable? `.cbp-hrsub { margin-top: -50px; }` fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/dca1eLqq/1/

Answer (score 0):

*"I would need this submenu (blue area) to be shown above the navigation bar (aka, pushing the nav bar and content bellow once opened) so it appears from top."* is not very clear.

> Do you also want the selected menu item to be below the submenu like
>   the rest of the menu

OR

> only the selected menu item to be above the submenu while the rest of
>   the menu is below the submenu.

Based on what I have understood, its the second part of the OR statement that you are looking for.

To achieve this, you need to make only a couple of changes. First, you need to remove the absolute positioning. That is, `.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub` would need to be changed to :

```
/* sub-menu */
.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub {
    display: none;
    position: relative;       /*change*/
    background: #47a3da;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

Second, you need to add the class `.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li.cbp-hropen`

```
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li.cbp-hropen {
    display: block;
}
```

Please see the snippet below. I think this is what you are looking for.

```js
/**
 * cbpHorizontalMenu.js v1.0.0
 * http://www.codrops.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * 
 * Copyright 2013, Codrops
 * http://www.codrops.com
 */
var cbpHorizontalMenu = (function() {

 var $listItems = $( '#cbp-hrmenu > ul > li' ),
  $menuItems = $listItems.children( 'a' ),
  $body = $( 'body' ),
  current = -1;

 function init() {
  $menuItems.on( 'click', open );
  $listItems.on( 'click', function( event ) { event.stopPropagation(); } );
 }

 function open( event ) {

  if( current !== -1 ) {
   $listItems.eq( current ).removeClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
  }

  var $item = $( event.currentTarget ).parent( 'li' ),
   idx = $item.index();

  if( current === idx ) {
   $item.removeClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
   current = -1;
  }
  else {
   $item.addClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
   current = idx;
   $body.off( 'click' ).on( 'click', close );
  }

  return false;

 }

 function close( event ) {
  $listItems.eq( current ).removeClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
  current = -1;
 }

 return { init : init };

})();
$(function() {
    cbpHorizontalMenu.init();
});
```

```css
.container > header {
 width: 90%;
 max-width: 69em;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 1.875em 3.125em 1.875em;
}

.container > header {
 padding: 2.875em 1.875em 1.875em;
}

.container > header h1 {
 font-size: 2.125em;
 line-height: 1.3;
 margin: 0 0 0.6em 0;
 float: left;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.container > header > span {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 9999;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 0.5em;
 padding: 0 0 0.6em 0.1em;
}

.container > header > span span:after {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 left: -12px;
 font-size: 50%;
 top: -8px;
 font-size: 75%;
 position: relative;
}

.container > header > span span:hover:before {
 content: attr(data-content);
 text-transform: none;
 text-indent: 0;
 letter-spacing: 0;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 110%;
 padding: 0.8em 1em;
 line-height: 1.2;
 text-align: left;
 left: auto;
 margin-left: 4px;
 position: absolute;
 color: #fff;
 background: #47a3da;
}

.container > header nav {
 float: right;
 text-align: center;
}

.container > header nav a {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 text-align: left;
 width: 2.5em;
 height: 2.5em;
 background: #fff;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin: 0 0.1em;
 border: 4px solid #47a3da;
}

.container > header nav a > span {
 display: none;
}

.container > header nav a:hover:before {
 content: attr(data-info);
 color: #47a3da;
 position: absolute;
 width: 600%;
 top: 120%;
 text-align: right;
 right: 0;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.container > header nav a:hover {
 background: #47a3da;
}
.cbp-hrmenu {
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 2em;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #47a3da;
 border-top: 1px solid #47a3da;
}

/* general ul style */
.cbp-hrmenu ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
}

/* first level ul style */
.cbp-hrmenu > ul,
.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner {
 width: 90%;
 max-width: 70em;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 1.875em;
}

.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li {
 display: inline-block;
}

.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a {
 font-weight: 700;
 padding: 1em 2em;
 color: #999;
 display: inline-block;
}

.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li.cbp-hropen {
    display: block;
}

.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
 color: #47a3da;
}

.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li.cbp-hropen a,
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li.cbp-hropen > a:hover {
 color: #fff;
 background: #47a3da;
}

/* sub-menu */
.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub {
 display: none;
 position: relative;
 background: #47a3da;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0;
}

.cbp-hropen .cbp-hrsub {
 display: block;
 padding-bottom: 3em;
}

.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner > div {
 width: 33%;
 float: left;
 padding: 0 2em 0;
}

.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner:before,
.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner:after {
 content: " ";
 display: table;
}

.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner:after {
 clear: both;
}

.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner > div a {
 line-height: 2em;
}

.cbp-hrsub h4 {
 color: #afdefa;
 padding: 2em 0 0.6em;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 160%;
 font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <div class="main">
        <nav id="cbp-hrmenu" class="cbp-hrmenu">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Parent</a>
              <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner"> 
                  <div>
                    <h4>Submenu</h4>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>

                </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
              </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Parent 2</a>
              <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner"> 
                  <div>
                    <h4>Submenu 2</h4>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  
                </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
              </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Parent 3</a>
              <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner"> 
                  <div>
                    <h4>Submenu 3</h4>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  
                </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
              </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Parent 4</a>
              <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner"> 
                  <div>
                    <h4>Submenu 4</h4>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  
                </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
              </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
            </li>
            
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:block; height:500px">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

Comment: Hey there Satwik and wow, this was detailed, thanks a bunch :)
Sorry, i dont think i explained myself properly (english isnt my first language), but i want the menu to look like this : http://i.imgur.com/enDhe5S.png

Aka, once the user clicks on the parent menu link, the submenu get expanded from top.Dont know did i explained it properly again :D

Answer (score 0):

The root of your problem is this CSS:

```
.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub{
    ...
    position:absolute;
    ...
}
```

Take that `position:absolute;` out of there, and the menu will push the page content down when it opens instead of floating over it.

You'll notice immediately an associated problem, however, which is that without absolute positioning, setting the element width to 100% only lets it get as wide as the `li` element that contains it.

Perhaps a better approach would be to keep that `position:absolute;`, but dynamically set the `margin-bottom` property of the `li` element in your `open()` function based on the contents of the submenu, so it pushes the page contents down.

Your updated `open()` method might look like this:

```
function open( event ) {
    if( current !== -1 ) {
        $listItems.eq( current ).removeClass( 'cbp-hropen' ).css("margin-bottom",0);
    }
    var $item = $( event.currentTarget ).parent( 'li' ),
    idx = $item.index();
    if( current === idx ) {
        $item.removeClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
        $item.css("margin-bottom",0);
        current = -1;            
    }
    else {
        $item.addClass( 'cbp-hropen' );
        $item.css("margin-bottom",$item.find(".cbp-hrsub").get(0).getBoundingClientRect().height+3);
        current = idx;
        $body.off( 'click' ).on( 'click', close );
    }
    return false;
}
```

Example:

```js
/**
 * cbpHorizontalMenu.js v1.0.0
 * http://www.codrops.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * Copyright 2013, Codrops
 * http://www.codrops.com
 */
var cbpHorizontalMenu = (function() {

  var $listItems = $('#cbp-hrmenu > ul > li'),
    $menuItems = $listItems.children('a'),
    $body = $('body'),
    current = -1;

  function init() {
    $menuItems.on('click', open);
    $listItems.on('click', function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
  }

  function open(event) {

    if (current !== -1) {
      $listItems.eq(current).removeClass('cbp-hropen').css("margin-bottom", 0);
    }

    var $item = $(event.currentTarget).parent('li'),
      idx = $item.index();
    if (current === idx) {
      $item.removeClass('cbp-hropen');
      $item.css("margin-bottom", 0);
      current = -1;
    } else {
      $item.addClass('cbp-hropen');
      $item.css("margin-bottom", $item.find(".cbp-hrsub").get(0).getBoundingClientRect().height + 3);
      current = idx;
      $body.off('click').on('click', close);
    }

    return false;

  }

  function close(event) {
    $listItems.eq(current).removeClass('cbp-hropen');
    current = -1;
  }

  return {
    init: init
  };

})();
$(function() {
  cbpHorizontalMenu.init();
});
```

```css
.container > header {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 69em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1.875em 3.125em 1.875em;
}
.container > header {
  padding: 2.875em 1.875em 1.875em;
}
.container > header h1 {
  font-size: 2.125em;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin: 0 0 0.6em 0;
  float: left;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.container > header > span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.5em;
  padding: 0 0 0.6em 0.1em;
}
.container > header > span span:after {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: -12px;
  font-size: 50%;
  top: -8px;
  font-size: 75%;
  position: relative;
}
.container > header > span span:hover:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 110%;
  padding: 0.8em 1em;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: left;
  left: auto;
  margin-left: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  background: #47a3da;
}
.container > header nav {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}
.container > header nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 2.5em;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 0.1em;
  border: 4px solid #47a3da;
}
.container > header nav a > span {
  display: none;
}
.container > header nav a:hover:before {
  content: attr(data-info);
  color: #47a3da;
  position: absolute;
  width: 600%;
  top: 120%;
  text-align: right;
  right: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.container > header nav a:hover {
  background: #47a3da;
}
.cbp-hrmenu {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 2em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #47a3da;
  border-top: 1px solid #47a3da;
}
/* general ul style */

.cbp-hrmenu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
/* first level ul style */

.cbp-hrmenu > ul,
.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 70em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1.875em;
}
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a {
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  color: #999;
  display: inline-block;
}
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #47a3da;
}
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li.cbp-hropen a,
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li.cbp-hropen > a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #47a3da;
}
/* sub-menu */

.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #47a3da;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
.cbp-hropen .cbp-hrsub {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 3em;
}
.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner > div {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 2em 0;
}
.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner:before,
.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner:after {
  clear: both;
}
.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner > div a {
  line-height: 2em;
}
.cbp-hrsub h4 {
  color: #afdefa;
  padding: 2em 0 0.6em;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 160%;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <nav id="cbp-hrmenu" class="cbp-hrmenu">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Parent</a>
          <div class="cbp-hrsub">
            <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner">
              <div>
                <h4>Submenu</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>

            </div>
            <!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
          </div>
          <!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Parent 2</a>
          <div class="cbp-hrsub">
            <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner">
              <div>
                <h4>Submenu 2</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>

            </div>
            <!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
          </div>
          <!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Parent 3</a>
          <div class="cbp-hrsub">
            <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner">
              <div>
                <h4>Submenu 3</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>

            </div>
            <!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
          </div>
          <!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Parent 4</a>
          <div class="cbp-hrsub">
            <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner">
              <div>
                <h4>Submenu 4</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>

            </div>
            <!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
          </div>
          <!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
        </li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="display:block; height:500px">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

**Edit: Making the submenu appear above the first-tier menu**

If you want the heading links to appear below the submenus along with the rest of the page content, set the `margin-top` property instead of `margin-bottom`, and make sure your sub-menu CSS (`.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub`) has its `top` property set to 0..

Example:

```js
/**
 * cbpHorizontalMenu.js v1.0.0
 * http://www.codrops.com
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * Copyright 2013, Codrops
 * http://www.codrops.com
 */
var cbpHorizontalMenu = (function() {

  var $listItems = $('#cbp-hrmenu > ul > li'),
    $menuItems = $listItems.children('a'),
    $body = $('body'),
    current = -1;

  function init() {
    $menuItems.on('click', open);
    $listItems.on('click', function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
  }

  function open(event) {

    if (current !== -1) {
      $listItems.eq(current).removeClass('cbp-hropen').css("margin-top", 0);
    }

    var $item = $(event.currentTarget).parent('li'),
      idx = $item.index();
    if (current === idx) {
      $item.removeClass('cbp-hropen');
      $item.css("margin-top", 0);
      current = -1;
    } else {
      $item.addClass('cbp-hropen');
      $item.css("margin-top", $item.find(".cbp-hrsub").get(0).getBoundingClientRect().height);
      current = idx;
      $body.off('click').on('click', close);
    }

    return false;

  }

  function close(event) {
    $listItems.eq(current).removeClass('cbp-hropen');
    current = -1;
  }

  return {
    init: init
  };

})();
$(function() {
  cbpHorizontalMenu.init();
});
```

```css
.container > header {
 width: 90%;
 max-width: 69em;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 1.875em 3.125em 1.875em;
}

.container > header {
 padding: 2.875em 1.875em 1.875em;
}

.container > header h1 {
 font-size: 2.125em;
 line-height: 1.3;
 margin: 0 0 0.6em 0;
 float: left;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.container > header > span {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 9999;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 0.5em;
 padding: 0 0 0.6em 0.1em;
}

.container > header > span span:after {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 left: -12px;
 font-size: 50%;
 top: -8px;
 font-size: 75%;
 position: relative;
}

.container > header > span span:hover:before {
 content: attr(data-content);
 text-transform: none;
 text-indent: 0;
 letter-spacing: 0;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 110%;
 padding: 0.8em 1em;
 line-height: 1.2;
 text-align: left;
 left: auto;
 margin-left: 4px;
 position: absolute;
 color: #fff;
 background: #47a3da;
}

.container > header nav {
 float: right;
 text-align: center;
}

.container > header nav a {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 text-align: left;
 width: 2.5em;
 height: 2.5em;
 background: #fff;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin: 0 0.1em;
 border: 4px solid #47a3da;
}

.container > header nav a > span {
 display: none;
}

.container > header nav a:hover:before {
 content: attr(data-info);
 color: #47a3da;
 position: absolute;
 width: 600%;
 top: 120%;
 text-align: right;
 right: 0;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.container > header nav a:hover {
 background: #47a3da;
}
.cbp-hrmenu {
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 2em;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #47a3da;
 border-top: 1px solid #47a3da;
}

/* general ul style */
.cbp-hrmenu ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
}

/* first level ul style */
.cbp-hrmenu > ul,
.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner {
 width: 90%;
 max-width: 70em;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0 1.875em;
}

.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li {
 display: inline-block;
}

.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a {
 font-weight: 700;
 padding: 1em 2em;
 color: #999;
 display: inline-block;
}

.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
 color: #47a3da;
}

.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li.cbp-hropen a,
.cbp-hrmenu > ul > li.cbp-hropen > a:hover {
 color: #fff;
 background: #47a3da;
}

/* sub-menu */
.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background: #47a3da;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0;
    top:0;
}

.cbp-hropen .cbp-hrsub {
 display: block;
 padding-bottom: 3em;
}

.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner > div {
 width: 33%;
 float: left;
 padding: 0 2em 0;
}

.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner:before,
.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner:after {
 content: " ";
 display: table;
}

.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner:after {
 clear: both;
}

.cbp-hrmenu .cbp-hrsub-inner > div a {
 line-height: 2em;
}

.cbp-hrsub h4 {
 color: #afdefa;
 padding: 2em 0 0.6em;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 160%;
 font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <div class="main">
        <nav id="cbp-hrmenu" class="cbp-hrmenu">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Parent</a>
              <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner"> 
                  <div>
                    <h4>Submenu</h4>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>

                </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
              </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Parent 2</a>
              <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner"> 
                  <div>
                    <h4>Submenu 2</h4>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  
                </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
              </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Parent 3</a>
              <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner"> 
                  <div>
                    <h4>Submenu 3</h4>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  
                </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
              </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Parent 4</a>
              <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner"> 
                  <div>
                    <h4>Submenu 4</h4>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  
                </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub-inner -->
              </div><!-- /cbp-hrsub -->
            </li>
            
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:block; height:500px">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

I realize that's not quite perfect, but all that's left is to clean up the spacing (such as line-height, padding, and margins) around your headings. I hope that helps!

Comment: This does help and it does push the content down, but is there a chance that the submenu opens above the menu and not bellow it, like this :

http://i.imgur.com/enDhe5S.png

This is the part that is giving me the most problems

Comment: @TorcaVino, I've updated my answer with another example.